# Display an image indicator when I click a save button via ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using .net MVC 3. I have an AJAX call to save questionaire answers, and I need some image indicator similar to loading icon to show users it was saved.

```
 <input id="SaveAccount"
        type="button"
        onclick="saveQuestioniare();"
        value=""
        alt="save account" title="save account" />
```

My AJAX call:

```
 function saveQuestioniare() {
           var formData = $("#SignupForm").serializeArray();
           $.ajax({
            url: '/Question/SaveQuestionaire?id=@ViewData["reviewId"]',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formData,
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                },
            success: function (json) {
                alert("Saved");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Reveal a hidden `<div>` in your success function using `$('#success-block').show()`? I take it you're using jQuery?

Comment: Can you write up a quick example?

Comment: Put the above in your success function, and then put this in your HTML: `<div style="display: none;">Saved OK</div>`. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to add a close button to that, or to hide it on a timeout `:)`.

Comment: Also, rename your function to `saveQuestionaire` - it's currently misspelt.

Comment: A further exercise for you would be to attach to the click event without the deprecated onclick attribute - see the `click()` function in the jQuery manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use additional plugins you can do it easly by css and js 10 line of code instead of 300/400 and more

first style your image to be where you want to be, for example:

```
<img src="...path to img" id="myimg" alt=""/>

#myimg{
margin:0;
position:relative;
top:20%;
bottom:20%;
left:0;
right:0;
display:none;
}
```

then in js do

```
$.ajax({ ....
beforeSend:function(){
$('#myimg').show();
},
success:function(){
$("#myimg").hide();
}
...});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a shadow box, like [Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/), a jQuery plugin and trigger it pointing to your favorite "spinner" image to indicate the loading, then, in the 'success' handler, close it.